Correct anonymization of submission using Latex
For a double blind review process, the venue (CHI) requires complete anonymization of submission files. Does this include the source files? More specifically, at the top in latex, you would normally specify authors as follows:
\author{Author name}
    \affiliation{Author affiliation}
\email{Author mail}

The template allows for "anonymous" keyword in the documentclass, hiding authors in the produced pdf. However, information would still be in the source files. So should one leave out these headers completely?

Are you required to submit the source file or just the pdf output?

@LazzaroCampeotti actually, this depends upon what the journal shares with reviewers. Usually, they just share a PDF with reviewers even if you upload the LaTeX files (but I have seen some journals that share TeX code with reviewers).

I would ask the journal. It all depends upon their workflow. If you want to be safe, replace your information with generic placeholders.

It is not a journal but a conference, CHI is the ACM Conference on Human Factors in Computing Systems.

I don't think it's an entirely unreasonable question. But isn't it just faster to go ahead and remove these from the source while you're thinking about it than worry?

If only I would have read the comments in the submission portal... There it states:

Please upload the source files of the paper in a zip format. The zip file must be under 300 MB. The source may be used if an accessible version of your PDF is not available. You do not need to perform anonymization in your source files. The files uploaded through this field are visible only to the paper chairs and accessibility chairs to create a more accessible version of your submission if needed by a reviewer.

Consequently, no anonymization is required. However, confirming with paper chairs, I was suggested to anonymize source files anyways, just to be safe. From that I understand that it doesn't matter whether there is author information in the source files or not.

In general the answer is no, you do not have to anonymize latex source files when submitting a paper to a conference using a blind process, because what you submit is the PDF file produced by latex, not the source files.
In the particular case of CHI 2025, the website states in Step 4:

Main Paper Deadline: Authors must submit the pdf of their paper, and related form data, before this deadline. No extensions will be granted. Any submissions showing ‘incomplete’ after the deadline will be deleted.

Which confirms that only the PDF file has to be submitted, not the latex source files.
